# eq:() doesn't work properly

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a code:

```
        $("#button").click(function () {
            for (var i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
                setTimeout(function () {
                    $(".rows:eq("+i+")").css("background-color", "blue");
                },500);
            }
        });
```

For some reason only the fifth element gets background-color grey. What is wrong?

Comment: care to put the html

Comment: When your first timeout function has executed, `i` has already been incremented to 4. Put the `for` loop in the timeout function.

Comment: you need to use a closuer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It has to do with the scoping of the `i` variable. It is bound to the for loop, not to the function invoked by setTimeout. Basically, when the delayed function is invoked, `i` is already increment to 4. In order to bind the current loop value of `i`, call another function. `i` is placed on the function stack and therefore the value if preserved.

It depends what kind of behavior your're looking for, but if you want to change the css of all elements at once @Josh's comment is the best.

```
$("#button").click(function () {
   setTimeout(function (){
     for (var i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
       $(".rows:eq("+i+")").css("background-color", "blue");
     }
   ,500);
});
```

Otherwise try:

```
bindItoFunc = function (i) {
  return function (){
    $(".rows:eq("+i+")").css("background-color", "blue");
  };
}
$("#button").click(function () {
  for (var i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
     setTimeout(bindItoFunc(i),500);
   }
});
```

Maybe a more elegant solution is to bind `i` as the `this` value of the function.

```
bindItoFunc = function () {
  $(".rows:eq("+this+")").css("background-color", "blue");
}
$("#button").click(function () {
  for (var i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
     setTimeout(bindItoFunc.bind(i),500);
   }
});
```

Question asker indicated that the background should change in order. In that case, change the waitMs based on `i`.

```
bindItoFunc = function () {
  $(".rows:eq("+this+")").css("background-color", "blue");
}
$("#button").click(function () {
  for (var i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
     setTimeout(bindItoFunc.bind(i),500+(100*i));
   }
});
```

Comment: Both solutions make all divs blue at the same time. I need to make them blue in order.

Comment: I've updated the answer, check the last example. Is this what you want to achieve?

Answer (score 0):

Try using `.delay()` , `.queue()` , recursively call `click` handler with incremented `.index()` of `.row` as parameter after initially setting `.eq()` to `event.data` : `0`

```js
// `0` : `event.data`
$("#button").click(0, function re(event) {
  var i = typeof event.data === "number" ? event.data : event;
  $(".row").eq(i).delay(500).queue(function() {
    $(this).css("background-color", "blue");
    if ($(this).index(".row") < 3) {
      re(i + 1)
    }
  })
})
```

```css
.row {
  color:orange;
  width:36px;
  padding:8px;
  font-weight:bold;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<button id="button">click</button>
<span class="row">0</span>
<span class="row">1</span>
<span class="row">2</span>
<span class="row">3</span>
<span class="row">4</span>
```

Comment: Why do we need this? `var i = typeof e !== "number" ? 0 : e;`

Comment: @Somaroton `e` will be `event` object of `click` within handler function at first call to `re` . Another option would be to pass `data` to click handler.

Comment: @Somaroton See updated post for implementation using `event.data`

Comment: Thanks for the solution.